# set focus in an ember application

Tags: javascript, focus, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to be able to set the focus to a textarea as a result of a mouse click not in that task area.

As a minimal example, let's say that I'm starting with a text and if you click on it, it gets replaced with a textfield. I can achieve this by a handlebars script:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#if isActive}}
  {{view Ember.TextField}}
  {{else}}
  <p {{action foo}}> Click Here to Enter text  </p>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

with a controller of

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isActive: false,
    foo: function(){
       this.set("isActive", true);
    }
});
```

This works to create the textfield on the click, but does not give focus to that text area (it takes a second click to be able to actually enter text).

Is there a good way to achieve this end? I could do something hacky by setting an ID in the template and selecting it with jquery, but that seems inelegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider extending Ember.TextField as follows:

```
App.FocusedTextField = Em.TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().focus();
  }
});
```

Then change you handlebars template to use it instead:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#if isActive}}
    {{view App.FocusedTextField}}
  {{else}}
    <p {{action foo}}> Click Here to Enter text  </p>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Furthermore, to reduce the `didInsertElement` and `this.$().focus();` which can seem as though you're mixing jQuery into your Ember modules -- and something I hate doing, you can use the Ember.JS way of specifying additional attributes for the `Ember.TextField`.

We can specify that we're interested in the HTML5 `autofocus` attribute:

```
Ember.TextSupport.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ["autofocus"]
});
```

We can then place the standard `Ember.TextField` onto our page without having to create another view to extend `Ember.TextField`:

```
{{view Ember.TextField autofocus="autofocus"}}
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MdzhN/

Comment: Good suggestion. A note to others, this property does not work in Internet Explorer versions < 10. [Autofocus Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)