# HTML5 autofocus not working on generated view

Tags: html, autofocus

I'm using EmberJS for my webapp and when I create a new record (set in edit mode), my first field (input text) has the autofocus="autofocus" parameter set. It works on Chrome the first time without problem, but not after.

The page loads once because it's an Ember app, and the views (record views) are being re-generated when I create a new record.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:
I have removed the autofocus property, and tried only to use Jquery focus() like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763643

```
App.FocusedTextField = Em.TextField.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().focus();
    }
});
```

Now, there is no focus even the first time. Also, if I tried replacing `this.$().focus();` with `this.$().hide();`, then the input is hidden. `this.$()` in the console shows the right input as well, but `focus()` just does not work!

Comment: Yes `autofocus` don't work for dynamic DOM according to the bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662496 You have to rely on `.focus()` method.

Comment: Since `autofocus` is done on pageload, I'd imagine you'll have to rely on scripting to manually set focus.

Comment: I'll go with the Jquery focus() function then, thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider moving your input to a view or a component and then do something like `this.$().focus();` in the `didInsertElement` function.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still does not work. Did same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/14763643, added logs everywhere (and the didInsertElement function is called successfully), but after the first time, there is no focus anymore.

Comment: Updated the post, without `autofocus` and only jquery focus() there is not even once autofocus on my textfield. I go thru the function `didInsertElement` tho

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact same issue with autofocus but the .focus() function did work for me.  Here's how I coded it:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="idTextbox"/>
```

javascript:

```
$('#idTextbox').focus();
```